# Magento Product images doesn't show up in admin

Tags: php, magento, import, e-commerce

I imported products and images through a **CSV file**. Able to view images in frontend but not in admin. It says **No image** when I open Images tab.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your .htaccess file inside the /media directory to .htaccess-old. This will absolutely resolve your image issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Did not manage to find an answer here, but I decided to post the solution that helped me.
Make sure that the following attributes exist and have valid values in import file:
**_media_attribute_id

_media_image

_media_position

_media_is_disabled**

This solved my problem under 1.7.2.

For previous versions try this solution if mine does not help:
http://www.lexitconsulting.com/2012/06/fixing-the-magento-product-import-script/

Comment: You are correct.  Just to add my observation the value for _media_attribute_id has changed somewhere between 1.9.1 and 1.9.3.  It is now 89.  This is why my export from a 1.9.1 install was not showing images when imported into a 1.9.3 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Bogdan's answer worked for me on 1.7.2. After loading data, verify that you are seeing entries in the catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table for the 'media_gallery' attribute of the products you are loading:

```
SELECT * 
FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
WHERE attribute_id = ( 
    SELECT attribute_id
    FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE attribute_code =  'media_gallery' )
```